# Magento 2.3.5 Estimate Shipping should be apply on Subtotal (Incl.tax)

Tags: magento2, magento-community, table-rates, magento2.3.5, shipping-tax

We're in trouble for a few days.

After upgrade to the latest Magento 2.3.5, we got an issue in estimate shipping calculation on the cart page.
Actually shipping takes value Subtotal (Excl. Tax) for calculation but we need to apply on Subtotal (Incl. Tax).

Table Rate Import file setting: Shipping should be 0 (zero) when price greater 40

From below image shipping should be 0 (zero)

[image]

Please check the admin store configuration changes.

Shipping Display Setting
[image]

Tax Calculation Setting
[image]

Table-rate Setting
[image]

Table-rate import file price Setting
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**found this:**

vendor\magento\module-tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector.php Line 596FF

$address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();

$address->setBaseSubtotalTotalInclTax($baseSubtotalInclTax);

$address->setSubtotal($total->getSubtotal());

$address->setBaseSubtotal($total->getBaseSubtotal());

**removed**

$address->setSubtotal($total->getSubtotal());

$address->setBaseSubtotal($total->getBaseSubtotal());

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Actually, this functionality was working before upgrade to the latest Magento 2.3.5. and after an upgrade, I'm getting an issue
and as per your comment, I will need to change vendor Magento tax module core file?

So Is this bug from Magento when upgraded to 2.3.5?

Answer (score 0):

When table-rates looks at the price it always looks at the tax-exclusive price and ignores promotional discounts as well.

Even though if the client wants to calculate based on subtotal with inclusive tax,

create plugin here,
Class \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address method: requestShippingRates

Manipulate the value of
$request->setPackageValue($item ? $item->getBaseRowTotal() : $this->getBaseSubtotal());

Thanks